# How do I install and use custom fonts?

Tags: fonts

I am trying to use the FiraMono font. I downloaded the `.otf` files and saved it in the `~/.fonts` directory and also ran `fc-cache -vf ~/.fonts` to update the cache.

Now, when I open elementary tweaks, I don't see it listed in the fonts. What am I missing?

Comment: Have you tried `sudo fc-cache` ...?

Comment: Yes, I did. Still no luck.

Comment: try the default font viewer and install the font through clicking install

Answer (score 13):

They should be placed in the following folders

**For personal use**

TTF files in `~/.local/share/fonts/truetype` (old way was `~/.fonts/truetype`)

OTF files in `~/.local/share/fonts/type1` (old way was `~/.fonts/type1`)

**For system wide use**

TTF files in `/usr/local/share/fonts/truetype`

OTF files in `/usr/local/share/fonts/type1`

Then `sudo fc-cache` and you should see the fonts.

An alternative way is to place fonts generally in `~/.local/share/fonts/` (old way was `~/.fonts/`).

Can you see the new fonts in Libre Office or similar office programs?

Comment: I did not have the folders truetype and type1 under /usr/local/share/fonts/. I had to create the type1 folder and copied the otf files there. I did see the type1 and truetype folders in /usr/share/fonts/. I copied the otf files to that location as well. I did sudo fc-cache but still no luck.

I do not have any office programs installed to try.

Thanks for your response.

Comment: Just installed LibreOffice Writer and I don't see it listed in the fonts either.

Comment: This was perfect, thanks man! One thing I did was also ran `sudo fc-cache -fv` (i.e. with the `f` and `v` options)

Comment: Why do we have button `Install` when opening font and that says `installed` after opening font again and we're unable to see the installed fonts in that way?

Answer (score 5):

TrueType fonts can be installed from file manager - double click the .ttf file, font manager will open, click "install".

To install multiple fonts system wide:
ttf files:

```
$ sudo cp ./yourpath/*.ttf /usr/share/fonts/truetype/
```

opentype:

```
sudo cp ./yourpath/*.otf /usr/share/fonts/opentype/
```

And then:

```
sudo fc-cache -fv
```

Answer (score 2):

I followed the instructions provided [here](http://linuxg.net/how-to-install-the-fira-sans-3-1-and-fira-mono-3-1-on-ubuntu-linux-mint-elementary-os-pinguy-os-and-elementary-os-systems/). This is what I did to have it working.

Created the FiraSans directory in /usr/share/fonts/truetype

```
$ sudo mkdir -p /usr/share/fonts/truetype/FiraSans
```

Moved the ttf font files to that directory and then updated the cache

```
$ sudo fc-cache -f -v
```

Initially, I did try with the OTF files and later moved to TTF files. I don't think that made the difference but just FYI.