# unable to use new added font in 6.1 Jólnir

Tags: fonts

I'm trying to use new downloaded font with Libre Office (also with Figma and Boxy svg). All system fonts are available except the newest installed.

Font is correctly installed in: `.local/share/fonts`

I also tried to add it manually in `usr/share/fonts/tuetype/new-font` and in `usr/local/share/fonts/truetype` and update cache with `sudo fc-cache -fv` as seen [here](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/658/how-do-i-install-and-use-custom-fonts), but it is still not listed with the other fonts :(

Any help would be very welcome. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Ok, works fine, problem was the font's name.

Also, via the install button, font is placed in `.local/share/fonts`
and unfortunatly does not work

To be listed in Libre Office and other apps available fonts, I had to place it manually in:

```
usr/share/fonts/truetype/my-new-font
```